# 3D interactive model for exporting Interactive html/JSON

Tags: blend4web, webgl

Apologies if this is an inappropriate posting, but I am new to Blender and not sure where to direct this, so any advice or suggestions will be much appreciated.

I am trying to create a 3D interactive model of a house in Blender that can be exported to HTML/Json using Blend4web.

I am progressing with the modeling side of the project, but struggling with the interactive aspects, specifically 'creating a menu' and basic animations linked to the model. I appreciate this is not something that can be simply explained in stackexchange, but would be grateful if anyone could advise whether Blender (Blend4web) is a good way to achieve this. Alternatively, if there is a different source of information that could provide an answer I would be keen to find out more.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Blend4Web should be more than capable of doing what you wish, you may have better luck and getting better answers at the official [Blend4Web Forum](https://www.blend4web.com/forums) I'd strongly recommend watching some tutorials and getting a good handstart at grasping the basics before asking any questions.

Comment: You are on the right track. You may need to study some animation basics for Blender. To see if this is what you are after, [Have a look at this.](https://3dxmedia.com/zwygart/) There are a number of YouTube channels that deal with Blend4Web.
[https://www.youtube.com/c/WillW](https://www.youtube.com/c/WillW)